# how to use django rest filtering with mongoengine

Tags: django, mongodb, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

Hi I am starting django 1.8.3 with mongodb using mongo engine to create rest api.

I am using rest_framework_mongoengine to do so.
I wanted to use a feature of DjangoFilterBackend for same.

My code is:

models.py:

```
from mongoengine import *    
from django.conf import settings    
connect(settings.DBNAME)

class Client(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=50)
    city = StringField(max_length=50)
    country = StringField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Country")
    address = StringField(default='')
```

Serializer.py

```
from client.models import Client    
from rest_framework_mongoengine.serializers import DocumentSerializer    


class ClientSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        depth = 1
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine.generics import *    
from rest_framework import filters    


class ClientList(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('name',)
```

I start getting  error
    QuerySet object has no attribute model

Don't know where its going wrong. If I remove filter_field It works but I can not use filter feature.

Any help would be of great use

Comment: Got one document for same, but couldn't find documentation for same.  https://github.com/qwiglydee/drf-mongo-filters/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Can you print the error trace for this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You can also perform the filtering by overriding the `get_queryset()` method and creating a generic filtering function.**

Here, we specify the filter fields tuple in the view as `my_filter_fields` on which we want to perform filtering. Then in our `get_queryset()`, we call a function `get_kwargs_for_filtering()`.

`get_kwargs_for_filtering()` functions iterates over the fields defined in `my_filter_fields` and checks if this was passed in the `query_params`. If the field is found then a key with the field name and value as the retrieved value is set in a dictionary `filtering_kwargs`. After the iteration is over, this `filtering_kwargs` dictionary is returned to the `get_queryset()` method.

This `filtering_kwargs` dictionary is used to filter the queryset then.

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine.generics import *    
from rest_framework import filters    


class ClientList(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    my_filter_fields = ('name', 'country') # specify the fields on which you want to filter

    def get_kwargs_for_filtering(self):
        filtering_kwargs = {} 
        for field in  self.my_filter_fields: # iterate over the filter fields
            field_value = self.request.query_params.get(field) # get the value of a field from request query parameter
            if field_value:
                # filtering_kwargs[field] = field_value
                field = self.get_serializer().fields[field_name]
                filtering_kwargs[field] = field.to_representation(field_value)
        return filtering_kwargs 

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Client.objects.all() 
        filtering_kwargs = self.get_kwargs_for_filtering() # get the fields with values for filtering 
        if filtering_kwargs
            queryset = Client.objects.filter(**filtering_kwargs) # filter the queryset based on 'filtering_kwargs'
        return queryset
```

Comment: If you override get_queryset() method than suppose you want to apply filter for all your items in your model than you have to manually check all items like suppose if I have to perform filter on name + country + city than again I will be checking all.
Additionally optional handling will be different
Looking for a general solutions.
Thanks for your time

Comment: Updated the ans with a generic solution. Check if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Gupta

This is working exactly the way I am looking for

Comment: If Client here is a mongo Document and does exclude work the same way?

Comment: @F_Ashik Mongoengine's `.exclude()`  works a little different than Django QuerySet's `.exclude()`. Check here http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.exclude

Comment: @RahulGupta Thanks for pointing me to the document. Do you know how I can execute a filter of **not contains** in a mongo Document queryset?

Comment: But its not working with ListField(ReferenceField(model)).
fields = ['products__name']
Can you help me with this?

Comment: I added `filtering_kwargs[field] = 
self.get_serializer().fields[field_name].to_representation(field_value)` to make it work for fields such as BooleanField. I hope you don't mind. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

here is a good method to do this work.
firstly, you should install django_mongoengine_filter rest_framework_mongoengine

```sh
pip install django_mongoengine_filter 
pip install rest_framework_mongoengine
```

secondly, you can write your owner Filter like this:

```py
import django_mongoengine_filter as filters

from app.models import User

class UserFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['name']
```

finally, you can use the UserFilter like this in view class:

```py
from app.models import User
from app.serializer import UserS  # use rest_framework_mongoengine to write serializer
from app.filters import UserFilter


class UserVS(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserS
    # override filter_queryset function
    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        filter = UserFilter(self.request.query_params, queryset=queryset)
        return filter.qs
```

Comment: But its not working with ListField(ReferenceField(model)).
fields = ['products__name']
Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is referring to Django 1.8. This is a question that is still important and valid in later versions of Django, DRF and MongoEngine.

At the time of this answer I am running

```
Django==4.1.3
djangorestframework==3.14
django-rest-framework-mongoengine==3.4.1
mongoengine==0.24.2
django-filter==22.1
# patched version of django-mongoengine-filter to support Django 4.0
# https://github.com/oussjarrousse/django-mongoengine-filter 
# Pull request https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-mongoengine-filter/pull/16 
django-mongoengine-filter>=0.3.5
```

The idea in this answer is to add filtering support to `django-rest-framework-mongoengine` using `django-mongoengine-filter` that is an replacement or an extension to `django-filter` and should work the same way as `django-filter`.

First let's edit the project/settings.py file. Find the INSTALLED_APPS variable and make sure the following "Django apps" are added:

```
# in settings.py:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...,
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework_mongoengine",
    "django_filters",
    # ...,
]
```

the app django_filters is required to add classes related to filtering infrastructure, and other things including html templates for DRF.

Then in the variable `REST_FRAMEWORK` we need to edit the values associated with the key: `DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS`

```
# in settings.py:

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # ...
    "DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS": [
        "filters.DjangoMongoEngineFilterBackend",
        # ...
    ],
    # ...
}
```

`DjangoMongoEngineFilterBackend` is a custom built filter backend that we need to add to the folder (depending on how you structure your project) in the file `filters`

```
# in filters.py:
from django_filters.rest_framework.backends import DjangoFilterBackend

class DjangoMongoEngineFilterBackend(DjangoFilterBackend):
    # filterset_base = django_mongoengine_filter.FilterSet
    """
    Patching the DjangoFilterBackend to allow for MongoEngine support
    """

    def get_filterset_class(self, view, queryset=None):
        """
        Return the `FilterSet` class used to filter the queryset.
        """
        filterset_class = getattr(view, "filterset_class", None)
        filterset_fields = getattr(view, "filterset_fields", None)

        if filterset_class:
            filterset_model = filterset_class._meta.model

            # FilterSets do not need to specify a Meta class
            if filterset_model and queryset is not None:
                element = queryset.first()
                if element:
                    queryset_model = element.__class__
                    assert issubclass(
                        queryset_model, filterset_model
                    ), "FilterSet model %s does not match queryset model %s" % (
                        filterset_model,
                        str(queryset_model),
                    )

            return filterset_class

        if filterset_fields and queryset is not None:
            MetaBase = getattr(self.filterset_base, "Meta", object)

            element = queryset.first()
            if element:
                queryset_model = element.__class__
                class AutoFilterSet(self.filterset_base):
                    class Meta(MetaBase):
                        model = queryset_model
                        fields = filterset_fields

            return AutoFilterSet

        return None
```

This custom filter backend will not raise the exceptions that the original django-filter filter backend would raise. The django-filter DjangoFilterBackend access the key `model` in `QuerySet` as in `queryset.model`, however that key does not exist in MongoEngine.

Maybe making it available in MongoEngine should be considered:
https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/2707
https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/issues/294

Now we can add a custom filter to the ViewSet:

```
# in views.py
from rest_framework_mongoengine.viewsets import ModelViewSet

class MyModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    filter_fields = ["a_string_field", "a_boolean_field"]
    filterset_class = MyModelFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

Finally let's get back to `filters.py` and add the `MyModelFilter`

```
# in filters.py
from django_mongoengine_filter import FilterSet, StringField, BooleanField
class MyModelFilter(FilterSet):
    """
    MyModelFilter is a FilterSet that is designed to work with the django-filter.
    However the original django-mongoengine-filter is outdated and is causing some troubles
    with Django>=4.0.
    """

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            "a_string_field",
            "a_boolean_field",
        ]

    a_string_field = StringFilter()
    a_boolean_field = BooleanFilter()
```

That should do the trick.