# Using restframework mongoengine how to create a queires?

Tags: mongodb, django-rest-framework, mongoengine, restframeworkmongoengine

#### models.py

```
from mongoengine import Document,  fields

class Tool(Document):
    Fruit = fields.StringField(required=True)
    District = fields.StringField(required=True)
    Area = fields.StringField(required=True)
    Farmer = fields.StringField(required=True)
```

#### Serializers.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_mongoengine.serializers import DocumentSerializer

from models import Tool

class ToolSerializer(DocumentSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tool
```

#### views.py file

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from rest_framework_mongoengine.viewsets import ModelViewSet as MongoModelViewSet

from app.serializers import *

def index_view(request):
    context = {}
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'index.html', context)

class ToolViewSet(MongoModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'Fruit'
    serializer_class = ToolSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Tool.objects.all()
```

So,I want to create queries like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tool/?Fruit=Banana` gives me all data for fruit banana only. Also, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tool/?District=Pune` gives me data for Pune district only .

Comment: Maybe a more up to date answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646858/how-to-use-django-rest-filtering-with-mongoengine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I haven't tried this solution myself yet, but AFAIK, in pure DRF with SQL database you'd use [Django-Filters package](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter) for this.

There's an analogue of it for DRF-ME, called [drf-mongo-filters](https://github.com/qwiglydee/drf-mongo-filters), written by Maxim Vasiliev, co-author of DRF-ME. It contains a decent set of tests,  you could use for inspiration.

Basically, you say something like:

```
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from mongoengine import Document, fields

from drf_mongo_filters.filtersets import filters, Filterset, ModelFilterset
from drf_mongo_filters.backend import MongoFilterBackend

class TestFilter(Filterset):
    foo = filters.CharFilter()

class TestView(ListAPIView):
    filter_backends = (MongoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = TestFilter
    serializer_class = mock.Mock()
    queryset = mock.Mock()

TestView.as_view()(APIRequestFactory().get("/?foo=Foo"))
TestView.queryset.filter.assert_called_once_with(foo="Foo")
```

Haven't tried doing the same with `ViewSet`s, but as they inherit from `GenericView`, I guess, they should respect `filter_class` and `filter_backends` parameters, too.

Comment: thank you for your great help for the start to end. :)

Comment: @KiranPrajapati Glad it helps. Cheers! =)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646858/how-to-use-django-rest-filtering-with-mongoengine